# Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name - DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>   Reverse for 'peliculas' not found. 'peliculas' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Django Version: 2.1.2
>   Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
>   Exception Value:
>   Reverse for 'peliculas' not found. 'peliculas' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.1
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Trabajos\Videoclub\videoclub_django',
>    'C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
>    'C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']

I just dont get what's happening

You can see full code here:

https://github.com/AngelQuesada/videoclub_django

This is the part where it fails (base_generic.html)

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Inicio
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'peliculas' %}">Peliculas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Directores</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Actores</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Géneros</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/">Administración</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = "videoclub"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^peliculas/$', views.PeliculaListView.as_view(), name='peliculas'),
    # url(r'^pelicula/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.DetailPeliculaView.as_view(), 
    name='detalle-pelicula'),
]
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I'm about to have a look at the Github link - but it's encouraged here to put the relevant snippets of code directly in your question, rather than link to it on an external site. This is just so that the question will still be useful later, for others, even if the link content changes (presumably you'll update your repo once you have an answer here that works for you). The relevant bits of code to put here would likely be your urlconf, and the relevant code in the views and template files.

Comment: Better to add the relevant code directly rather than adding external links.

Comment: you're right guys, I edited it, thank you all!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've namespaced your URLs in the `videoclubs` app. So rather than just `{% url 'peliculas' %}` you should use `{% url 'videoclub:peliculas' %}`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you soooo much!

Comment: It works if you are using templates on app-level templates not project-level templates. It works!

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
...
return redirect('app_name:view_name')
```

If you get this error while debugging your view you should use the above code.