# Django Url NoReverseMatch at issue

Tags: django, django-urls

I don't know why I am getting this issue with my code. I've tried a bunch of stuff to resolve it but I can't

**NoReverseMatch at /property/**

`Reverse for 'property_detail' not found. 'property_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/property/Django Version:3.0.5Exception Type:NoReverseMatchException Value:

`Reverse for 'property_detail' not found. 'property_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Exception Location:E:\django_projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677Python Executable:E:\django_projects\env\Scripts\python.exePython Version:3.7.4Python Path:

```
['E:\\django_projects\\hotel\\src\\project',
 'E:\\django_projects\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37',
 'E:\\django_projects\\env',
 'E:\\django_projects\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

html code

```
<ul class="probootstrap-main-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'property:property_list' %}">Properties</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'agents:agents_list' %}">Agents</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'about:about_us' %}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact:send_mail' %}">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

project/urls (project directory)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('property/', include('property.urls', namespace='property')),
    path('agents/', include('agents.urls', namespace='agents')),
    path('about/', include('about.urls', namespace='about')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls', namespace='contact')),
]
```

propert/urls (app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name= 'property'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.property_list, name='property_list'),
    path('<int:id>', views.property_detail, name='property_detail'),
]
```

property/views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import (Property, Category)
from .forms import ReserveForm

def property_list(request):
    property_list = Property.objects.all()
    template = 'list.html'
    context = {
        'property_list': property_list,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)

def property_detail(request, id):
    property_detail = Property.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        reserve_form = ReserveForm(request.POST)
        if reserve_form.is_valid():
            reserve_form.save()
    else:
        reserve_form = ReserveForm()

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'property_detail': property_detail,
        'reserve_form': reserve_form
    })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111036/reverse-for-not-found-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or-pattern-name-djan?rq=1

Does this answer your question?

Comment: You're missing the part of the template that causing the error. The part that says `{% url 'property_detail' id=id %}`. Also, you should look a bit into [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Comment: Thanks folk! I had to check my whole html code for property and I found the error I was not using the namespace to retrieve the data from property_detail                                                             ```{% url 'property:property_detail' property.id %}``` that was the mistake